# How to populate multiple query parameters in an API using Cucumber Scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I'm using Rest Assured, combined with Cucumber to test an API which has multiple query parameters. Let's say, the API is

```
http://dev.abcd.com/mainpath?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

I want to vary the param values based on a Cucumber scenario

```
Scenario Outline: API returns successfull response on different parameters
    
    Given Main path API is hit 
    When "<param1>","<param2>","<param3>" are passed
    Then the response returns a status code of 200

Examples:
  |param1|param2|param3|
  |value1|value2|value3|
  |value4|value5|value6|
```

I went through the documentation and another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293367/restassured-passing-list-as-queryparam), but the parameters method is now deprecated and also I'm not sure if this is how it can be done.

Most of the tutorials and the documentation directly specify passing the parameter in `given().queryParam().then()` format, where I'll have to hard code the parameters, which I don't want.

Any pointers on this regards with be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the feature file a bit and have used the [cucumber data tables](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable) feature to fetch the values. Have included a small snippet using rest assured to make a call according to your URI

**Feature** :

```
Given I perform GET operation on URL with param values
| param1 | param2 | param3 |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| Value4 | Value5 | Value6 |
```

**Step Definition :**

```
@Given("^I perform GET operation on URL with param values$")
public void i_perform_GET_operation_on_URL_with_param_values(DataTable arg1) {

    List < Map < String, String >> list = arg1.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String Param1 = list.get(i).get("param1");
        String Param2 = list.get(i).get("param2");
        String Param3 = list.get(i).get("param3");

        String response = RestAssured.get("http://dev.abcd.com/mainpath?param1=" + Param1 + "&param2=" + Param2 + "&param3=" + Param3).then().extract().asString();
        //Edit suggested by Vamsi Ravi
        //String response = RestAssured.given().baseUri("http://dev.abcd.com").basePath("/mainpath").queryParam("param1",Param1).queryParam("param2",Param2).queryParam("param3", Param3).when().get().then().extract().asString();

        System.out.println("The Content is " + response);
    }

}
```